# PHP expression to match variable-length text

Tags: php, regex

If I have the string:

```
Detroit 10    New Jersey 2 (FINAL)
```

Is there a way to match `Detroit 10` and `New Jersey 2` in a single regular expression?

I can't figure out how to do it if the city names are different lengths and some have spaces in the city name.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If your string actually has three spaces, you can just split by that.

Comment: split on the numbers. that'd give you 3 strings. "detroit 10", "new jersey 2", and "(final)". Once you've got the separate city/scores, split those up into city and score will be easier.

Comment: Waleed Khan, I just used your method (which split it into an array with 2 values) then stripped off the unnecessary spaces and "(FINAL)".  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, using the numbers to delimit the end of a city name.

Like:

```
/([^\d]*\d+)/
```

Comment: Ahh, this is a great start.  Now I just need to find a way to start it with a capital letter (and not a space).  The first match works, but the second match finds "   New Jersey 2".  Let me see if I can figure it out from here.

Comment: it would be simpler as: /([^\d\s][^\d]*\d+)/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "Detroit 10    New Jersey 2 (FINAL)";

preg_match_all("/(\w+ )+\d+/", $str, $m);

print_r( $m[0] );// the resulted strings are in this table $m[0]
```

Hope it helps